# How to add a method to link_to do ViewHelper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Thats the original Devise logout link which works:
`link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)`

Because of the  and the  I had to switch to this kind of link. The problem now is the link try to find the user `sign_out`

Tried:

```
  <%= link_to (destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) do %>
      <i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</span>
  <% end %>
```

and

```
  <%= link_to (destroy_user_session_path, method => :delete) do %>
      <i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</span>
  <% end %>
```

and

```
  <%= link_to (destroy_user_session_path, :method = 'delete') do %>
      <i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</span>
  <% end %>
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Remove the space between `link_to` and `(`.

Comment: need to check on that problem tommorrow, seems more a problem with my js, because he dont recognize the data-method

Answer (score 0):

I would do,

```
<span>
  <i class="icon-off">
  </i> 
  <%= link_to("Logout",destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)%>
</span>
```